# showing proper labels in matplotlib pie chart

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, pie-chart

I am trying to build a pie chart using matplotlib. Here is my code:

```
party = data['Name'].groupby(data['Party']).count()
party
```

The code above leads to:

```
Party
The Centre Party                22
The Christian Democrats         16
The Green Party                 25
The Left Party                  21
The Liberal Party               19
Name: Name, dtype: int64
```

Then, the following code

```
"plt.pie(party, labels=party)"
```

creates a pie chart with those values (e.g., 22, 16, 25) as labels.

What I want is to show those party names as labels. Any suggestion? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can use -

```
plt.pie(party, labels=party.index)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion!